# I cannot see my usb hard drive on Fedora 17

Tags: external-hard-drive, fedora, mount

I plug the hard drive to the computer but it cannot be recognize on the machine. What could I do to mount it automatically. I am running fedora 17 and my hard drive is ntfs.

Comment: I can't even use Fedora 17, I went back to using Xubuntu.

Comment: Are you getting any error msg like unable to mount?

Comment: no error or no sight for the driver